# table and graph side by side

Tags: tables, graphics

I'd like to have a table of estimation results on the left hand side of the page and then a graph (of the estimation's residual) directly side by side with that table on the right hand side of the page.

I've not seen this done, given that they're quite different latex objects. Anyone, any experience?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Your graph is just an image file? Do you need separate captions for each? If yes, see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361280 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/ helps. If you don' need separate captions it might be as easy as placing the `\includegraphics` immediately after the  `\begin{tabular}...`  (without an empty line between them).

Comment: or see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269097/aligning-images-and-subtables-in-a-table

Comment: Maybe it would be easy when you take the two into one float as subfloats.

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{table}
            Here the table
        \end{table}\hskip
        \begin{figure}
            Here the picture.
        \end{figure}
    \end{figure}

Comment: @ThomasBenko, don't nest floats in floats. A correct (better) way is use `minipage`s or `tabularx` or `tabular` (with `p` column type) environments and if needed separated captions use `caption` or `capt-of` package for table and figure caption. See solutions in given links.